# Error when trying to add a filter to a view

Tags: filter, odoo-14

I'm working on an Odoo 14 module but I ran into a problem when trying to add a filter to a view that allows viewing records for today.
Here is the error i get

```
`Error: Control panel model extension failed to evaluate domain:/n{}`
```

Here is my code

```
<record id="models_cashouts_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">cash_in_out.request.search.view</field>
        <field name="model">cash_in_out.request</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search>
                <field name="appliquand_uid"/>
                <field name="amount"/>
                <field name="create_date" string="Date"/>
                <field name="acceptor_uid" />
                <filter string="Aujourd'hui" name="today" domain="[('create_date', '&gt;=', (context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), ('create_date', '&lt;=', context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))]" />
            </search>
        </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
<filter name="today" string="Today" domain="[('create_date', '=', context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The [context_today](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/core/py_utils.js#L230) returns a `datetime.date` and the date [strftime](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py_extras.js#L624-L643) function only handles `%Y`, `%m`, and `%d` placeholders. Odoo will fail while evaluating `%H`.

The first value of the filter domain tries to subtract a time delta from a string, you need to remove the `.strftime()`. To use the  `datetime` format, you need to use `datetime.datetime` object.

You can use the datetime `combine` function to set time to `00:00:00`:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0)))
```

To fix the issue, remove the unsuporrted placeholders: `%H:%M:%S`

Comment: Why you removed the accept flag?